# Solve the differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following DE

$$\left(x \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)dx - \left(y \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-x\right)dy = 0$$
 I could not find a way to start this problem. I tried the ways I know but I could not move further.

Comment: That's a PDE add that tag to your question

Comment: No, it isn't.  This is simply y as a function of the single variable x or x as a function of the single variable y.  There is no **partial** derivative.  user363533, seeing "y/x" in the sine function, my first thought would be to define a new variable, u= y/x (my second thought might be to define u= sin(y/x)).

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(x \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)dx - \left(y \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-x\right)dy = 0$$

[image]

There is no closed form for the integral with a finite number of standard functions.

Answer (score 0):

hmm i had a crack at it, didn't solve it but maybe someone else can manage where i failed (and at least gives op a starting place):

- after dividing through by x (it wouldn't be defined anyway if x could be 0) I see that the $v=\frac{y}{x}$ substitution seems ideal
- rearrange to get dy/dx on one side
- $\frac{dy}{dx} = v + \frac{dv}{dx}$   and    $\frac{dx}{dy} = 1-x \frac{dv}{dx}$ (tried both)
- Seperate variables
- get integrals that i can't do :
  $ln|x| = \int{\frac{sin(v)}{1+sin(x)-v.sin(v)}dv}$ or $x = \int{\frac{sin(v)-v}{v^2}dv}$